# Excel currency string value with Applescript

Tags: excel, applescript

Here's my situation: I have an InDesign file that needs to read an Excel spreadsheet that has item descriptions, quantities, and prices. The descriptions are text, the quantities are numbers, and the prices are currencies. I'll be getting these documents from all over the world, so the price column is in a currency format with various currency symbols.

I was able to find an Applescript that converts the full sheet into a text array for InDesign to read, but the price cells only give me the value, not the formatted value.

So when my rows looks like this:

```
Item A | 4 | 3.00 €
Item B | 7 | $4.50
...
```

and I run this script:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
   open file "excelFilePath"
   set theWorkbook to active workbook
   set theSheet to sheet 1 of theWorkbook
   set theMatrix to value of used range of theSheet
   set theRowCount to count theMatrix
   set str to ""
   set oldDelimiters to AppleScript's text item delimiters
   repeat with countRows from 1 to theRowCount
       set theRow to item countRows of theMatrix
       set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ";"
       set str to str & (theRow as string) & "|"
   end repeat
   set AppleScript's text item delimiters to oldDelimiters
   close theWorkbook saving no
end tell
tell application id "com.adobe.InDesign"
   tell script args
       set value name "excelData" value str
   end tell
end tell
```

then I get this:

```
Item A,4,3,
Item B,7,4.5,
...
```

but I need this:

```
Item A,4,3.00 €,
Item B,7,$4.50,
...
```

How do I get the string value of the currency?

Comment: I don't have a Mac to check, but I'm pretty sure that that script with the input from the top will not produce the output you described (either of them).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use *string value* instead of just *value*.

```
    set theMatrix to string value of used range of theSheet
```

Cheers!
Funtom